# Regexp для удаления <> внутри элементов XML

Tags: регулярные-выражения, plsql, xmlparser

Имеется сlob (Oracle) с XML
Часть данных "испорчена", т.е. содержит символы <> внутри элементов, например:

```
<Text>Адрес получателя: <user1@mail.ru>; ФИО; почта2 <user2@mail.ru></Text>
```

Элементы могут повторяться.
Для избежания ошибок парсинга хочу удалить символы <> внутри элементов text используя REGEXP_REPLACE. Помогите с регуляркой, пожалуйста
https://regex101.com/r/d600mX/1 - пока получается найти только содержимое элемента, и то 1
Вероятно есть и другие решения задачи, буду рад услышать

Comment: Не до конца уверен. Звучит так, что вам надо найти все "<" и ">" внутри конструкций вида <Text>,,,</Text>. И... И все условия? Что-то такое - https://regex101.com/r/0GtZnw/1 ?

Comment: все верно, так захватывает </Text>

Comment: согласен, а так: /(?<!Text)(<|>)(?!\/?Text)/gm  ? Добавил в последнее условие необязательный  "/" перед Text

Comment: да, так работает. спасибо!